# NUnit - Asserting Exception and properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'd like to Assert that an exception is being thrown and then check some of the properties of the thrown exception.

I was under the impression that I could do something like the following:

```
ICommand command = CreateCommandObj();
Assert.That( () => command.DoWork(), Throws.TypeOf<ArgumentException>(),                        
                     Has.Property("ParamName").EqualTo("myParam") &
Has.Property("Message").EqualTo("myMessage") );
```

However this doesn't even compile and looking at the expected parameters for Assert.That I can't see how I would be able to do this?  I'm sure I have used this before though...

Note the above is a contrived example to illustrate the point, ignore the fact I am looking for an ArgumentException on a method that doesnt except any parameters :)

Any help appreciated.

1) Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, sorted.

I need to use the following syntax:

```
ICommand command = CreateCommandObj();
Assert.That( () => command.DoWork(), 
                   Throws.TypeOf<ArgumentException>()
                   .And.Message.Equals("MyMessage"));
```

This approach allows me to check properties on the thrown exception.  I can add any number of And or Or's to the Assert.

Thanks everyone for the suggestions.

Comment: This almost worked for me, however I had to change the constraint to be `Throws.TypeOf<ArgumentException>().And.Message.StringMatching("MyMessage"));`. I assume this is due to changes made to the NUnit framework since this post was made.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => {
    command.DoWork();
});
Assert.AreEqual("myMessage", exception.Message);
```

Comment: The best answer in my opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You test for exceptions with the `[ExpectedException]` attribute on your method. e.g.

```
[Test] 
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
public void Test_SomeMethod()
{
    something.SomeMehthod();
}
```

You can set the properties of the expected exception in the constructor of the ExpectedException attribute.

**EDIT**
You could also specify your test attributes like the following:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(ExpectedException = typeof(InvalidOperationException), ExpectedMessage = "Somethings not right")]
public void Test_SomeMethond()
{
    something.SomeMehthod();
}
```

Comment: Isn't ExpectedException an obsolete method of asserting for exceptions?

I thought this had been superceded by either Assert.Throws<> or using the Constraint syntax?

Comment: I guess ultimately it should be down to which ever method is best to maintain readability and consistency with the tests.

I suppose it could be argued your suggested way is better due to less lines of code.  And it is certainly readable and easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Try && - *logical and* versus *bitwise and*

**Edit**:

I think you're looking for Assert.Throws if you're using the constraint interface.  Not sure how you would assert on message.  I think the old style is clearer for what you're trying to accomplish:

```
  try
  {
    command.DoWork();
    Assert.Fail("ArgumentException Expected");
  }
  catch (ArgumentException e)
  {
    Assert.AreEqual("Expected Message", e.Message);
  }
```

Comment: Tried it but same compilation problems.  I think I am mixing something up because I can't seen an Assert.That method overload that will allow me to do what I want.

Adding compilation error messages to question.